# WinAPI convert from virtual key to character in C

Tags: c, string, windows, winapi, unicode

I have a C program and I registered a callback to listen for VM_KEYDOWN events

The events are received correctly and for every keystroke I get the virtual key code `key`. Now I'm trying to covert such virtual key code (which is just an index of the button on the keyboard) to an actual character. I know that not all the keys return a character (like "F2") but I don't care, I'd like to convert the key code to a character whenever possible

This is what I'm doing now:

```
void ConvertKey(unsigned int key)
{
    BYTE keyboardState[256];
    WORD out;
    GetKeyboardState(keyboardState);
    int res = ToAsciiEx(key, MapVirtualKeyEx(key, 0, GetKeyboardLayout(0)), keyboardState, &out, 0, GetKeyboardLayout(0));

    // out contains the character
}
```

On the `out` variable I get the character, unfortunately it doesn't take into account SHIFT or CTRL so if I simply type 'a' or 'A'(pressing SHIFT+a) I always get an 'A'.

In other words, it doesn't sense the SHIFT (or CTRL I guess) and doesn't output the correct character

**EDIT**

here my message pump and the callback

```
LRESULT CALLBACK GetInput(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *keyboard = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;

    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        ConvertKey(keyboard->vkCode);
    }

    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI MsgPump()
{
    HHOOK hKeyHook;
    HINSTANCE hExe = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    hKeyHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL,(HOOKPROC)GetInput, hExe, 0);
    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you should look into the GetAsyncKeyState function https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx. With this function, you can ask, if a specific key, like LSHIFT, was pressed side the last call of the function.

Comment: The state of the modifier keys is returned by GetKeyboardState().  You are doing something else wrong if it cannot see the SHIFT or CTRL key being pressed.  Like not implementing a proper message loop that calls GetMessage().  Such a message loop also ensures you get WM_CHAR, the kind of message you should be listening for instead of having to use this kludge.

Comment: I tried and I failed: calling GetAsyncKeyState() doesn't solve the issue because I cannot just say "ok, I've got 'a' but SHIFT was pressed then it's 'A'". I can't because with different keyboard layouts you get different symbols when you press SHIFT. 'a' and 'A' are the easy example. SHIFT+5 gets '&' or '*' depending on the layout

Comment: @HansPassant want to see the message pump I wrote?

Comment: No.  Use WM_CHAR instead.

Comment: @HansPassant could you please provide an example callback which uses the event WM_CHAR?

Comment: The callback is your window procedure. Handling [WM_CHAR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276.aspx) should be straight forward. The *wParam* carries the character code you are looking for.

Comment: ok thanks, I made an edit to my question

Comment: @IInspectable looks like wParam carries the message id (WM_CHAR)

Comment: You never explained, that you set up a low-level keyboard hook. That's a relevant detail, and leads to the follow-up question: Why? (Do read the documentation for `WM_CHAR`. It provides the character code as the *wParam* parameter.)

Comment: Hmya, I suppose I should have guessed at a low-level keyboard hook.  Stop right now, you cannot get this reliable.  That's why there is also a WH_KEYBOARD hook.  It runs in-process so can accurately detect the process' keyboard state.

Comment: @HansPassant so what do you suggest? Using WH_KEYBOARD

Comment: You are mixing and matching a lot of unrelated concepts, and I cannot tell what kind of program you are trying to make. Your program also assumes one keystroke per character, which is also not necessarily true. Read a good book, like the 5th edition of the Petzold book if you want to learn how to write Windows desktop programs. (I'm sure there's a book that teaches services, but you should probably read the Petzold book anyway. Most Windows programmers start with the GUI.)

Comment: @andlabs I'm not assuming one keystroke per character, there's no 1:1 relationship between button presses and character on screen I know. I receive a WM_KEYDOWN so I know the user pressed a *button* on the keyboard. WM_CHAR seems more like what I need

Comment: @RaymondChen could you please show me a version of that code which uses WM_CHAR?

Comment: `case WM_CHAR: res = (TCHAR)wParam:` But now you edited the question to say that you are using a low level hook. Low level hooks do not have enough information to convert keypresses to characters.